# Comma-separated values from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make an associate array to loop through.
Both values I want come from query2 but the second one is a column with numbers from 1-40. When I normally make an `combine_array` it says that the arrays are not equally long as PHP treats the for example number 10 as two values somehow. But I want to connect the numbers with the names equally.

I've tried the `foreach` loop but that didn't work out so far.
How can I make such an array?

PS. I need the array to combine with the values from $query to get the Artikelnaam values from another table.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE  klantnummer = '{$_SESSION['userid']}'";
$query2 ="SELECT Artikelnaam, Artikelnummer FROM products";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt2 = $db->prepare($query2);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt2->execute();
while($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {


$combined = "";
foreach($row["Artikelnummer"] as $row['Artikelnummer'] => $row['Artikelnaam'])   {
$combined = $row['Artikelnummer'] . $row['Artikelnaam'] . ",";
echo $combined;
```

Comment: Learn about `JOIN`. Much easier that way.

Comment: It doesn't work to me with the WHERE clause. don't know why.

Comment: Well you're obviously doing something wrong then. It should be super simple.

Comment: Why not using `JOIN` ?? 
u may find this link useful


 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)